# NTP: How to know a complete time sync is happened in NTP

Tags: linux

Here is the scenario:

I have a two node machine. The master node synchronizes its time with some external source and then sets a reference time source for the slave node to sync its time.

I wanted to know how to check that the time is synchronized on the master node and reference time source is set and now ntpdate command can be run on slave node.

I read about NTP and found out that if ntpq -p  shows an asterisk in the output like below:

```
remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================  
10.20.94.1      10.20.78.3    6 u   13   64  327    0.407  893.508  770.685 
*127.127.1.0     .LOCL.       0 l   16   16  377    0.000    0.000  0.001
```

which means the master node is ready.
But it is working sometimes and sometimes not.

I want to know where i am going wrong or there is some specific pattern to look for in the ntpq o/p.

Answer (score 1):

Run `ntpq -c rv`. In the first line of the output, you should see `clock_sync` if the clock is synchronized. A full description of the first line of the output can be found here: http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/decode.html#sys